# Create Apache reverse proxy to a dynamic port

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, docker, networking, reverse-proxy

A app runs inside a docker container on port `8080`. The container IP is `172.17.0.2`.

Now i have a sub-domain, say `subdomain.domain.com`, so i create a apache reverse proxy server `ProxyPass / http://172.17.0.2:8080` and i can access my app which is inside the container.

Now i change the port of the app to `9090`, so now i would have to change the virtual host configuration, and i don't want to do that. I want this thing to be completely dynamic, so is there a way were i can keep my port value a variable inside the configuration file so i can access it by calling `subdomain.domain.com:9090`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay i found the answer, I can use the `RewriteEngine` instead of `ReverseProxy`.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?([0-9]*)    http://172.17.0.2:$1/ [L,P]
```

and to access the container with a specific port i would have to make a request like:
`subdomain.domain.com/{{port}}`

So if i change my app port to something else, say `7777`. I will have to change nothing just make a request to `subdomain.domain.com/7777`